# Google Maps Geocode to include name of premises

Tags: php, google-maps

Using the code below which works well:

```
function geocode($address){
    $return = array();
    $address = urlencode($address);
    $key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=$key&address={$address}";


    if (!function_exists("\curl_init")){
        \load_curl();
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,6000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    $resp_json = \curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);
    if($resp['status']!=='OK') return false;

    foreach($resp['results'] as $res){
        $loc = array(
            "zipcode"=>null,
            "formatted"=>null
        );
        foreach($res['address_components'] as $comp){
            if(in_array("postal_code", $comp['types'])) 
                $loc['zipcode'] = $comp['short_name'];
        }
        $loc['formatted'] = $res['formatted_address'];
        $loc['lng'] = $res['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        $loc['lat'] = $res['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $return[] = $loc;
    }
    return $resp;
}
```

However when I search for an address such as "*ZOOM DIGITAL PRINT UNIT 36  BINLEY IND EST HOTCHKISS WAY COVENTRY CV3 2RL*" the formatted address is brought back as "*Starley Court, Hotchkiss Way, Coventry CV3 2RL, UK*"

Is there a way to get the business name included in this request or can it be found by another API?

Comment: Geocoder is for geocoding addresses. Places API to retrieve places or *businesses* information. I'd suggest you read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) is used to convert addresses into lat/lng coordinates and vice-versa or to find addresses for a given place ID.

To get business information you should use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro). E.g. try searching for "Zoom Digital Print Ltd" in Google's Autocomplete [example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) and you'll get this business name.

Hope this helps!